# 50% Healing Reduction

Tags: league-of-legends

Ignite, Impure Shots, Explosive Shot and Executioner's Calling (and maybe others) all reduce an enemy's healing down to half. What happens if you try to stack 2 or more of these? Does it go like 50 > 75%; 50 > 100% or does it just stay at 50% all the time regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not stack, so it stays at 50% no matter how many times you apply the debuff, however, applying a second healing reduction ability will refresh the timer.

Answer (score 1):

None of the healing reduction debuffs stack but applying one on top of another will refresh the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite will stack damage true damage but not the healing reduction debuff.  Like they said it maxes at 50%  or everyone would run ignite or play gp/trist/mf/fizz.

Comment: Gangplank doesn't have built in healing reduction anymore. Just letting you know.

Comment: Also, damage does **not** stack with multiple Ignites.  New Ignites simply "take over" the older instance(s).